Regular expression for letters within a Unicode range?
I'm using the re module in Python. Let's say I want to find all Arabic letters in a string. Essentially I want to combine \w with [\u0600-\u06FF].
Is there a way of doing this? Specify both a character range and a class, where both must match?
If not possible with python's native re module, is it possible with regex from pip?
This question is about combining two different criteria for a single character match (i.e. intersection), it's not really about Arabic letters. And besides, all the answers to questions regarding matching Arabic letters completely miss the many alternate forms that can appear in Arabic text.

How do I contest a false marking as duplicate? The points of the questions are nothing alike. And the answer to my question is far more accurate.

Below implements an intersection of \w and the documented Arabic Unicode ranges from the Unicode.org Code Charts for the re module as well as the equivalent using the regex module.  The regex module supports intersection as documented in Unicode Technical Standard #18.
import re
from itertools import chain
import unicodedata as ud
import regex

def ranges(L):
    '''Convert list of Unicode code points to ranges, e.g.
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 10 ,11]
    to
    '\U00000001-\U00000004\U00000007\U00000009-\U0000000B'
    '''
    retval = '['
    i = iter(L)
    start = next(i, None)
    while start:
        n = next(i, None)
        if n is None or n > start + 1:
            retval += f'\\U{start:08x}'
            start = n
            continue
        while (m := next(i, None)) and m is not None and m == n + 1:
            n = m
        retval += f'\\U{start:08x}-\\U{n:08x}'
        start = m
    return retval + ']'

arabic = (range(0x600,0x700),      # Arabic
          range(0x750,0x780),      # Arabic Supplement
          range(0x8a0,0x900),      # Arabic Extended-A
          range(0x870,0x8a0),      # Arabic Extended-B
          range(0x10ec0,0x10f00),  # Arabic Extended-C
          range(0xfb50,0xfe00),    # Arabic Presentation Forms-A
          range(0xfe70,0xff00))    # Arabic Presentation Forms-B

# Unicode codepoints that match \w in ranges specified
ucp = [ord(n)
       for n in re.findall(r'\w',
                           ''.join(chr(x)
                                   for x in chain(*arabic)))]

letters = ranges(ucp)
print(letters)
pattern = re.compile(letters)
# Search the entire Unicode range
alluni = ''.join(chr(x) for x in range(0x110000))
retval = re.findall(pattern, alluni)
# Lengths of generated range pattern and codepoint list should match.
print(len(retval), len(ucp))

# Using regex module and intersection syntax.
# Note \w in regex module captures category Mn (Nonspacing Marks)
# while re module does not, so excluding them to get the same result.
# && denotes intersection, -- denotes subtraction and is only supported
# using the regex.VERSION1 flag.
retval = regex.findall(r'[\w&&[\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\u08a0-\u08ff\u0870-\u089f\U00010ec0-\U00010eff\ufb50-\ufdff\ufe70-\ufeff]--\p{M}]', alluni, flags=regex.VERSION1)
print(len(retval), len(ucp))

Output:
[\U00000620-\U0000064a\U00000660-\U00000669\U0000066e-\U0000066f\U00000671-\U000006d3\U000006d5\U000006e5-\U000006e6\U000006ee-\U000006fc\U000006ff\U00000750-\U0000077f\U000008a0-\U000008c9\U00000870-\U00000887\U00000889-\U0000088e\U0000fb50-\U0000fbb1\U0000fbd3-\U0000fd3d\U0000fd50-\U0000fd8f\U0000fd92-\U0000fdc7\U0000fdf0-\U0000fdfb\U0000fe70-\U0000fe74\U0000fe76-\U0000fefc]
1024 1024
1024 1024


Thank you. It's surprising to me that something as fundamental as an intersection was so hard for me to find, and apparently isn't so well known or widely supported (in our sample of two python libraries at least).

Although a strict intersection of the set of letters and the set of Arabic characters (at least in Unicode terms should be 1144 according to latest version of Unicode. 1145 if you use script extensions instead. The values will differ from Python version to Python version.

@Andj I was targeting what \w considers a letter in standard re.  I get your number with [\p{Arabic}&&\p{L}].

@MarkTolonen, are you aware of a concrete definition of \w? It would be interesting to know how exactly it differs from Unicode's.

I know it's the alphanumeric a and underscore but Python's definition of alphabetic differs from Unicode, maybe more aligned with POSIX standard?

@Andj No, maybe Python's is an error?  Include non-spacing marks with \w makes sense as regex does.  That makes a decomposed word still match.

It isn't just that, \w in re makes mincemeat of many African languages and many writing scripts. Sklearns default tokeniser which uses re will delete entire words as non word tokens.

But for Python, some methods follow Unicode, some diverge, some are based on other standards and not Unicode. But nothing is explicitly stated as to what is what.

@MarkTolonen, out of interest I tried adding the Arabic Mathematical Alphabetic Symbols block to your code, and the results I got were: 1165 1165 and 1024 1165

The only answer I could come up with, inspired by this answer for matching any letter, is this:
arabic_letters = re.findall('[^\\W\\d\u0000-\u05FF\u0700-\U0010FFFF]', my_string)

This works fine, my only problem with it is it feels wrong. Instead of specifying the range 0600-06FF, I have to specify everything before and everything after this range. It got even more convoluted when I wanted to add other ranges of Arabic characters:
arabic_letters = re.findall('[^\\W\\d\u0000-\u05FF\u0700-\uFB4F\uFE00-\uFE6F\uFF00-\U0010FFFF]', my_string)

(there may be even more ranges I need to add, haven't checked yet)

You are putting the inversion specifier ^ at the start of the range.  What happens when you leave that out?

Why not [\w\u0600-\u06ff]?

@MarkRansom - note that \W is the inverse of \w as well. it's easier to understand in the context of the answer I linked to.

@MarkTolonen that would match any letter OUTSIDE the range, and also any character WITHIN the range, I believe

\w matches any Unicode letter by default. You said you wanted to combine \w and 0x600-0x7ff and that's the way to do it.  There are values in the 0x600-0x700 range that aren't considered Unicode letters and \w matches a lot more than ASCII letters.  Maybe you want the intersection of those ranges instead of union?

Looks like you want Intersection but it isn't implemented in Python's re module yet.

@MarkTolonen exactly, I want an intersection :) thanks. Do you know if it's implemented by the regex package?

Yes, added an answer.

Although it's important to realise that regex's \w is different to re's \w.
